# Breaking a <form> tag between different table columns

Tags: html, css

I have a `<form>` which I am using within a very simple table structure, which is attempting to be as simple as the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/LDnfQ/

I similarly am trying to create three columns in a row that spans 100% of the viewport, each of which resize automatically based on the size of the viewport so that they are evenly distributed across the length of the viewport.

I currently have a haml structure which is unfortunately complicated by the fact that I am breaking up a `<form>` and its `<input>`'s across the three columns. I don't know how to preserve the `<form>` scope across the three child `<div>`s of the row with out messing with the desired CSS behavior of each column acting like a proper column of a 1/3 of the size.

Past a certain viewport size, the column width is not distributed evenly in my implementation of the Table like structure where as in the first fiddle it is.

Here is my .haml

```
.front-page-test

  =form_for :proficiency_test do |f|
    .column-test
      =f.label :first_name, 'First Name'
      %br
      =f.text_field :first_name
      %br
      =f.label :family_name, 'Family Name'
      %br
      =f.text_field :family_name
      %br
    .column-test
      -@country = 
      -right_countries = @country.collect{|x| [x,x]}
      =f.select(:country, right_countries, :prompt => "Select a Country")
      %br
      =f.label :email, 'Your Email'
      %br
      =f.text_field :email
    .column-test
      %br
      = f.label :agency?, "Are you working with an agency?"
      %br
      = f.label :agency?, "Yes", value: "true"
      = f.radio_button :agency?, true
      = f.label :agency?, "No", value:"false"
      = f.radio_button :agency?, false 
      %br
      =f.label :agency_name, 'If so what is your agency\'s name?'
      %br
      =f.text_field :agency_name
      %br
      =f.submit "Submit"

      .all-caps
        ENGLISH PROFICIENCY TEST
```

with the following CSS:

```
.front-page-test{
 width:100%;
  display: table;
 table-layout: fixed;
 border-spacing: 20px;
 padding:40px;
background:#3ab9a0;
position:relative;
 top:-60px;
 color:white;
 height:200px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.column-test{
  display: table-cell;
 width:30%;
 }
```

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lkxh4hgy/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What is wrong with the second fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Lkxh4hgy/)? Looks like three columns inside a form to me?

Comment: the only thing is that the column sizes don't get resized past a certain viewport width. Where as in the first fiddle it does.

Comment: Ah. And you can't put .front-page-test inside the form? Or style the form as the "table element" instead of the .front-page-test?

Comment: Adding display:table-row-group (aka. tbody) to the form works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `.column-test` to have `display: inline-block` solves it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkxh4hgy/1/